# How to convert ArrayList instanceObject to toString

Tags: java, sql

i want to convert the instance of class which is in ArrayList to toString i have here my code

User class:

```
public class User { 
    // ...

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.fullname = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.fullname;
    } 

    public ArrayList<User> getTheLikers() {
        ArrayList<User> user = new ArrayList<>();
        user.add(this);

        return user;
    }
```

Post class:

```
public class Post {
    public ArrayList<User> getLikers() {
        User a = new User();
        ArrayList<User> b = a.getTheLikers();

        return b;
    }
```

and here is the code where i should get the getLikers()

```
while(rs.next()) {
    User a = new User();
    Post b = new Post();
    String name = rs.getString("people_who_like");
    a.setName(name);

    ArrayList c;
    c = b.getLikers();
    String liker = c.toString();
    p.addElement(liker);
}
```

i have already convert it to toString as you can see.. but it shows that i have display my value but it is in null

Comment: Tip: According to your code, `getTheLikers` can be `static` so you won't need dummy instance to call it.

Comment: For starters give meaningful variable name.

Comment: What exactly would your preferred output look like?

Comment: if u want list like this how could u over come this requirement with local variable of list?? what is p please provide required code.

Comment: it should show 
Example
[Clark Kent]
[Lois Lane]

but instead it shows
[null]
[null]

it displays in a JList by the way p is adding element in a JList

Comment: No idea what you're trying to achieve. Both bits of code make no sense out of context.

Comment: First give some more explanation what u trying to achieve i got the thing that u try to get all liker entity but if u make local variable and call into the some other method how it could be piossible @CyranLemoncito?

Comment: Where is getLikers(); method that is giving you likers?

Comment: first i want my value to go to getLikers() but as you can see i got an ArrayList<User> getLikers which is in the Post Class so to be able to use it I need to have a method to get it so I make a getTheLikers() in User Class

Comment: @CyranLemoncito if u using getThelikers that is fine but u using for that new object of user i think so that will not having any value inside it. so are u sure it will give output?

Comment: that is what i think about also i instantiate a User = new User(); but is there any other way to get the getTheLikers method to my getLikers()?

Comment: @CyranLemoncito just declare the variable Static so u can access same copy of that user inside any mehtod. do u know what is static variable is?

Comment: yes @Krishna but i dont know where to declare the variable

Comment: @CyranLemoncito out side of the method and that will be exist only one copy threw out the System. have look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

Comment: thank you very much for your patience! i will try to read the tutorial and find a way to solve my problem

Comment: @CyranLemoncito its okey u are new try to learn this basic will be helpful and may be i got your logic that according to some parameter u trying to find likers and trying to show that.

Answer (score 0):

To convert `ArrayList` into a `String`. That is specifically what the question says.

```
ArrayList c;
c = b.getLikers();    
String liker = ""; 
for (String s : c){
    liker += s + "\t";
}
```

Comment: i dont think so this ans is match to require even 10%

Comment: The answer matches if you just read the title. Actually the title to question is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao to thing method he just said means giving all the elements into the one like is it?

Comment: @Krishna : The question specifically states the toString method is providing null values. Its essentially returning the name of the arraylist object. He needs the values in them. You need to parse through the list and append each value into a string. That's precisely what my code does.

Comment: @SunilHV if that is just mening of having name of all elements then arraylist.tostring() giving same output then what is meaning of overriding tostring method?

Comment: im sorry guys i have a bad title.. im new to java and also a newbie in programming so please bear with me im trying to explain my problem in the best possible way

Comment: @SunilHV i tried your code but it still shows null value

Comment: @CyranLemoncito its okey buddy and may be i think problem is not with the tostring method its may be what happen inside your getlikers(); method i think so.

Comment: yeah i tried to convert it to toString() but it wont let me return String, because it is in ArrayList so it wont let me return

Comment: @CyranLemoncito change it return type into the String if that wont affect the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When using **Java 8** you can use [String#join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) for this:

```
String liker = String.join(", ", c);
```

or the Stream API:

```
String liker = c.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

**Pre Java 8** you have use e.g. Guava for this or write our own function

```
public static String listToString(final List<String> list) {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        result.append(list.get(i));
        result.append(", ");
    }
    result.append(list.get(list.size() - 1));

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: what if he is not running on java 8?

Comment: im trying to output it in a Jlist

Answer (score 0):

Even the list having the method `List.toString()` where u can get list into the String format.

how ever here the one thing that u can use your list to convert into the string.

Use the static variable for the list.

```
    public class MainClass {
    static ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        arrayList.add("Krish");
        arrayList.add("Krish1");
        arrayList.add("Krish2");
        arrayList.add("Krish3");
        arrayList.add("Krish4");

        System.out.println(arrayList.toString());

    }
}
```

Similar u can use tostring method like this. if u using just arraylist then it will give out put in string format.

other way to do this.

```
public static String arrayliststring(ArrayList arrayList) {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            buffer.append(arrayList.get(i).toString() + " ");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

hope this helps and for java 8 as ifloop said that is correct.

Comment: it should display in a JList, and honestly i can't remove the method ArrayList<User> getLikers().. it is part of my Machine Problem and it is required

Comment: @CyranLemoncito well m not asking you to remove it. may be null thing is getting while getting liker that is what i meant.